# HACluster Config for Stardog

Tags: rdf, apache-zookeeper, high-availability, stardog

I have three machines running Stardog in High Availability Cluster configuration -what's the endpoint URL I should use to read and write to Stardog, and where should I configure it? I intend to use the SNARL API/protocol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have deployed the Proxy in all three machines as well, you should point your Stardog clients to any of the Proxy instances. The URL would be:

`snarl://<proxy ip address>:<proxy port>/`

As an aside, we have a mailing list for these types of questions at https://groups.google.com/a/clarkparsia.com/forum/#!forum/stardog

Comment: for both read and write? I assumed the write should go to the leader and then propagated to the followers.

Comment: The clients only need to point the Proxy and the Proxy will handle the redirection to the leader in case of writes. Further, reads will be distributed amongst the whole cluster.

Comment: fantastico! thats what I was looking for. cheers-mate!